# typescript cannot find module alias

Tags: typescript, webpack

typescript shows error **"Cannot find module '@contexts' or its corresponding type declarations."**

The folder structure:

```
Project
 |    
 +-- src
     |  
     +-- index.tsx
     +-- contexts
         |
         +-- testContext.tsx
```

Below is the importing example:

```
import { useTest } from "@contexts"
```

Below is a part of 'webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  ...otherSetting,
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@contexts": path.resolve(__dirname, "src/contexts"),
    } 
  }
}
```

Below is a part of 'tsconfig.json':

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...otherOptions,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@contexts/*": ["contexts/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Despite of the error, it can read the state from importing. However, it still shows an error.
How can I get rid of it?

If you know anything about this, plz answer the problem.
Thank you

Comment: add "include": ["src/**/*"] in your tsconfig